# writing function but been getting this error

Tags: oracle, plsql

the question:

**Write a blocK PL/SQL that display the total commission amount of a job id. Use function “compute_commission” that accepts a job id equal to 9 and return his total commission of all corresponding employees.**

the error:

> `Error at line 11: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE"
>
> 1. CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compute_commission (C_employee_id in number)
> 2. RETURN number
> 3. is `

the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compute_commission (C_employee_id in number)  
 RETURN number
 is 
 sum_commission number;
begin
select sum(job_id)
into sum_commission from employees
where employee_ref_id = C_employee_id;
return sum_commission;
end compute_commission;

declare 
cal_sum_commission number;
begin
cal_sum_commission = compute_commission(cal_sum_commission);
dbms_output.put_line ('employee commission is: ' || compute_commission(cal_sum_commission);
end;
```

Comment: Put a slash `/` into a line that follows `end compute_commission;` to terminated CREATE FUNCTION.

Comment: i dont understand, im new

Comment: You need a "/" so the "create function" statement is executed. That is what @littlefoot is saying. Add a "/" on the line after "end compute_commission;" and try again. Note that you need ":=" as assignment variable. You have "cal_sum_commission =..." that will fail as well.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compute_commission (C_employee_id IN NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   sum_commission  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM (job_id)
     INTO sum_commission
     FROM employees
    WHERE employee_ref_id = C_employee_id;

   RETURN sum_commission;
END compute_commission;
/

DECLARE
   cal_sum_commission  NUMBER := 12345;
BEGIN
   cal_sum_commission := compute_commission (cal_sum_commission);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
      'employee commission is: ' || cal_sum_commission);
END;
/
```

Note that I modified anonymous PL/SQL block and

- added local variable's value (otherwise you'd pass `NULL` to the function) (you'll, of course, use some valid value; this - 12345 - is just an example)
- used local variable in `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`
- terminated statement with a semi-colon (you've had a colon)
- fixed assignment operator (`:=` instead of just `=`)

---

Also, is `sum_commision` really sum of `JOB_ID` values? Looks strange to me ...